# Deploying a .NET 6 WebApi to AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-fargate, .net-6.0

**Setup:**

I have a .net 6 minimal API that I need to deploy to my client's AWS environment.  The only AWS services that I can use for the deployment are Lambda, Beanstalk, or Fargate.  I run my project locally via Docker.  My API is pretty lightweight.  All it does is take a form submission, validate it, and write it to an MySQL RDS instance.  There are 4 other APIs that I need to deploy as well but none of them are resource intensive.

For my AWS environment, I have programmatic access with MFA.  I've gotten a session token using AWS sts.

I have installed the latest dotnet tools for AWS which include templates for AWS Serverless API and AWS Lambda on .NET 6.  I cannot get those template applications to deploy either.

I am hoping to avoid Fargate since it seems like overkill for what I need, but if someone thinks that's the best way forward for me given I'm using docker locally, I'm open to hearing it.

**Problem:**

Plain and Simple: I have no idea how to deploy the project.  From Visual Studio, if I attempt to publish the container to ECR, I get an error saying "Missing required parameter: --instance-profile".  If I attempt to publish to Lambda or Beanstalk, I get a CloudFormation error saying "The security token included in the request is invalid (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId)"

I created a personal AWS account and was able to publish there using programmatic access token with NO MFA requirement.  So, my guess is that the issues are tied to me using a Temporary Access Token due to the programmatic access token profile I am using requiring MFA.  But I'm not sure how I can get around this or what I'm doing wrong.  Using my temporary access token profile, I am able to create s3 buckets, list resources, etc so I know the profile is setup correctly.

My credentials file looks like:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AWSACCESSKEYID
aws_secret_access_key = AWSACCESSKEY
aws_session_token = AWSSESSIONTOKEN_GIVEN_BY_AWS_STS_GET-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue.  I wasn't authenticating the right way.

You need to create an IAM Role to delegate access to an IAM User then create a policy that requires MFA and attach that to the policy to the user.

The details of how to handle all this are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/mfa-credentials.html)